# Scrapy: extrat items within JSON response

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I'm trying to pull individual objects out of a JSON response. The following is the response I get from the website I'm trying to scrape:

```
[{"name":"AAA 404","id":"AAA404","sections":[{"id":"5393643","name":"40053","instructor":"Dellabough"}]},{"name":"AAA 604","id":"AAA604","sections":[{"id":"5393644","name":"40054","instructor":"STAFF"},{"id":"5393645","name":"40055","instructor":"Dellabough"}]}]
```

Using the following code (and a spider), I'm able to get the "name", "id", and "section".

```
    def parse(self, response):
    jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())

    for i in jsonresponse:
        print i["id"], i["name"], i["sections"]
```

This gives me the following:

```
ID =  AAA404 NAME =  AAA 404 SECTION =  [{u'instructor': u'Dellabough', u'id': u'5393643', u'name': u'40053'}]
ID =  AAA604 NAME =  AAA 604 SECTION =  [{u'instructor': u'STAFF', u'id': u'5393644', u'name': u'40054'}, {u'instructor': u'Dellabough', u'id': u'5393645', u'name': u'40055'}]
```

Now, what I'd like to do is pull the "instructor", "id", and "name" that are within the sections. Ultimately, I will need to tie this information with the overall ID and section, but for now I'm mostly concerned with being able to extract this information in a usable format like I can do for the overall ID, Name, Section.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the *sections* dicts using an inner loop, the id and name from each i will be associated with each:

```
for dct in i["sections"]:
     print(i["id"], i["name"], dct["instructor"], dct["id"], dct["name"])
```